# Facebook sharing image preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, preview

I am trying to "rebuild" the Facebook share dialog.

I have a website where people can rate products and afterwards they can share a link to this product, whereas the producs are owned by different companies.

So before sharing the link I want that the user has the possibility to preview what the share would look like and show it in preview window on my webiste.

I have managed to get the og:imgage from the website, but lots of website don't have the ogp tags. So I am trying to find out how Facebook chooses the thumbnail that is seen in the share preview.

Do you have any hints?

All the best

Comment: why not just use the share dialog? for a custom solution, you would need to authorize the user with publish_actions.

Comment: I have the Facebook button in my page which is used for the share dialog but i want that the users can in a way what the post would look like even before they hit the button. 
Furthermore this is interesting because i want to add an email button to.

Comment: We use a number of heuristics (guesses) to pick the best image when OG tags are missing. We don't have any public documentation on the methods we use though.